# Ruby modifying body of a Mail Interceptor using register_interceptor and delivering_email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, actionmailer, interceptor

I've got a working intercept up and running in my Ruby on Rails application. Currently I can modify the subject just fine using the technique below, but for some reason I can not modify the Body.

Inside of my /config/initializers I register the interceptor like so:

```
ActionMailer::Base.register_interceptor(MailIntercept)
```

Inside of /lib/ i have a file called mail_intercept like so:

```
class MailIntercept
  def self.delivering_email(message)
   message.subject = "Modified Subject"
   message.body = "Modified Body"

   if message.to.split("@").last == "olddomain.com"
    message.subject = "Domain is olddomain.com, safe to display message"
    message.body = message.body + "Domain is olddomain.com, safe to display message" 
    else
    message.subject = "Domain is NOT olddomain.com, hide message"
    message.body = "Domain is NOT olddomain.com, hide message."
   end

   end
end
```

Problem #1: The body doesn't get modified, ever.

Problem #2: The application that is sending emails has multiple email addresses being sent as BCC. If the email is to olddomain.com, I want to display the message body. Otherwise, I want to strip the message body and just display a message.

I'm pretty sure that this delivering_email only gets called once when the email is sent, and not multiple times for each of the BCC's. Even if I did a loop through the TO, CC, and BCC and then modified the body it would modify the body for everyone. Is there a better way to go about this?

Comment: I'm trying to do the same, but since the body is an `Mail::Body` class object is seems that asigning a string like message.body = "string" maybe that doesn't work. Did you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I checked the code, it is working fine for me I am using Rails 3.2.6

I guess the problem may be at the action mailer method invoking place